# Draw a force-extension graph with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

im new with tikz and id like to draw a force-extension graph of a steel. I have no idea how to do this. I only draw squares or circles with it.

[image]

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: This is a perfect job for `PGFPlots` (graphing extension to `TikZ`). http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html

Comment: Ok thank you, i try to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a template for your graph, you just need to insert your data.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    height=5cm,
    width=\textwidth,
    xmin=0,   xmax=7.5,
    ymin=0,   ymax=15,
    xtick={0,0.5,...,7.5},
    minor x tick num=4,
    ytick={0,5,...,15},
    minor y tick num=4,
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=1},
    tick pos=left,
    ymajorgrids,
    ylabel=Kraft F in \si{\kilo\newton}
]
\addplot[mark=*] coordinates {
        (0,0)
        (0.2,7)
        (1,8)
        (4,11)
        (7,9)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph]